# Transfer a file via scp with key auth

Tags: linux, ssh, authentication, scp

I need to transfer a file from machine `source` to machine `target`, executing the scp command on `source` machine.
The `source` machine has a private key, and the `target` machine has `source`'s public key installed. 
Is there something else i need to do to tranfer the file? Like, install `target`'s public key on `source`?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

> Is there something else i need to do to tranfer the file?

Generally, no. Verify that you're able to `ssh` into the server – as long as you're able to log in, both SCP/SFTP should work as well.

> Like, install target's public key on source?

*Technically* yes, but this already happens semi-automatically – it's the "host key fingerprint" dialog that you see on first connection. As the client is running interactively, it can just prompt you to approve the server's public key (whereas the server cannot really do that for client keys).

If you want to fully automate this part, the location of the host-key cache depends on client. For the `scp` and `sftp` commands in OpenSSH, the accepted host keys are in `~/.ssh/known_hosts` on the client system.

(The verification of the target's public key has the same purpose as verifying a website's HTTPS certificate, except there are no CAs that could vouch for it, so I would recommend *not* trying to make the client blindly accept all keys.)